# Discord calculation bot command

Tags: python, discord

```
############# BOT calculator #################
#-------------------------------------------------
import operator
action = {
    "+": operator.add,
    "-": operator.sub,
    "/": operator.truediv,
    "*": operator.mul,
    "**": pow
}
print(action['-'](50, 15)) # 35

@bot.command(name='c')
async def calculator(ctx, arg1, arg2, arg3):
    calcresult = action[arg2](arg1, arg3)
    await ctx.send('---CALCULATION---')
    await ctx.send(calcresult)
    await ctx.send('---CALCULATION---') 
############# BOT calculator #################
```

не работает калькулятор бот в дискорде L*(

Comment: Обычно под **не работает** подразумевается ошибка или неожиданное поведение. Пожалуйста уточните свой вопрос чтобы было понятно в чём проблема.

Answer (score 2):

У вас пропущены библиотеки "discord" и "commands" из "discord.ext"

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
```

А так же не объявлен и не запущен сам бот:

```
bot = discord.Client()
bot.run('BOT_TOKEN')
```

Полный код:

```
############# BOT calculator #################
#-------------------------------------------------
import operator
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

action = {
    "+": operator.add,
    "-": operator.sub,
    "/": operator.truediv,
    "*": operator.mul,
    "**": pow
}
print(action['-'](50, 15)) # 35

bot = discord.Client()
bot.run('BOT_TOKEN')

@bot.command(name='c')
async def calculator(ctx, arg1, arg2, arg3):
    calcresult = action[arg2](arg1, arg3)
    await ctx.send('---CALCULATION---')
    await ctx.send(calcresult)
    await ctx.send('---CALCULATION---') 
############# BOT calculator #################
```

Comment: я про команду бота спрашивая а не про то как бот запустить

Comment: calcresult = action[arg2](arg1, arg3) вот эта строчка кода не работает вы ее перепесали опять

Comment: @Gena, потому-что вы не конвертировали строку в число